# Equivalent of "genvarname" in Python

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, string-concatenation

How can I generate a variable name from a string (say a concatenation of a letter and a number) ?

In Matlab, this task can be easily done using **[genvarname](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/genvarname.html)**

Comment: Umm I kind of hope there isn't any :p That's messy! Do you absolutely, positively need that?

Comment: keep your data out of your variable names.  Use a `dict` or *maybe* `getattr`, depending on the situation.

Comment: See if this thread helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python
it contains comments about `getattr`, `exec`, `eval` and why it's actually best to use dictionaries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a *really* bad way (undefined behavior), but I think it shows the path to a more reasonable technique.

Your current namespace is really a dictionary under the covers:

```
>>> local_namespace = locals()
>>> name = "myVarName"
>>> local_namespace[name] = 'VarData'
>>> myVarName
'VarData'
```

But that's not very DRY - you have to write the name of the variable twice! It would be nice to use a variable that stored the name of our dynamically created variable so we didn't have to type it twice:

```
>>> name
'myVarName'
```

obviously doesn't work for this. But we can use our dictionary again:

```
>>> local_namespace[name]
'VarData'
```

So now we can store and recall the value associated with our variable. But wait - there's no need to use the special `locals()` dictionary for this - an ordinary dictionary will do!

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[name] = 'VarData'
>>> d[name]
'VarData'
```

And now we have all these added benefits, like being able to keep track of the names of several of these variables in a list:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.append('myVarName')
>>> l.append('anotherVarName')
```

Dictionaries even do this for us:

```
>>> d['anotherVarName'] = 123
>>> d.keys()
['myVarName', 'anotherVarName']
```

Unless you're doing terrifically wacky things, it's hard to imagine how constructing variable names could be more useful than using a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec("")`.

But you **really**(!!!) don't want to.

```
>>> name="myVarName"
>>> exec(name+"='VarData'")
>>> myVarName
'VarData'
```

Comment: You can also add it manually to the dict of your scope, but you really don't want to do this either.